# Nested TouchableOpacity Parent onPress not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchableopacity

i had this issue where i'm trying to make sure the parent's onPress is triggered, but it wont

im trying to create a custom touchableOpacity component that able can be reusable, that wrap other Component so it can decide if the children can be shown or not and decide/alter what happen when the children component is pressed.

```
const CustomTouchable = (children, onPress) => {
   function handleOnPress = () => {
      if(validation){
         onPress();
      }
   }

   return <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleOnPress}>{children}</TouchableOpacity>
}


const MainComponent = () => {
   function onPress = () => {console.log('test')}

    <CustomTouchable onPress={onPress}>
       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Text>Press Here</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
    </CustomTouchable>
}
```

but the parent onPress is not triggered, how can i trigger it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the touch event is received by the children and not the parent. Assign following prop to your Child Component

```
pointerEvents={"none"}
```

Comment: thank you! this is the one that i looking for, but sadly i cant upvote your answer since i just recently joined this website.

Comment: Thats alright. glad to help, You can accept this as the correct answer by clicking on the tick icon.

Answer (score 0):

Make the second TouchableOpacity disabled like this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
  <TouchableOpacity
    disabled
    style={styles.button}
  >
    <Text>Press Here</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: hey thank you for the answer, but in my case sometimes the children is just a regular component, that dont have disabled props

Comment: Ok then if the children is not a "Button", for instance a View, then it will work without doing anything

Comment: oh really? okay cool, but i have another question lets say i made the outer touchableOpacity as custom component, how to pass the disabled props into its children?

Comment: Can you post an other question with example ? Then I can answer with code example. I am not sure of what you want to do.

Comment: okay, but since stackoverflow only allow 1 question every 90 minutes, i just update the question instead. thank you

Comment: In your Maintcomponent you can add disable props directly in the children of CustomTouchable